# GRASS v.overlay return "ERROR: Attribute not found"

Tags: gis, grass

I am trying to intersect two shapefiles. I was successful in doing so in QGIS by calling v.overlay. I want to do the same task on HPC using the command line.

I am trying the following:

```
module load grass/7.8.4
grass78 -c rivs_slice.shp -e $HOME/grassdata/
#Linking external vector data to PERMANENT Mapset:
grass78 $HOME/grassdata/PERMANENT/ --exec v.external input="rivs_slice.shp" output=rivers
grass78 $HOME/grassdata/PERMANENT/ --exec v.external input="lakes_slice.shp" output=lakes
grass78 $HOME/grassdata/PERMANENT/ --exec v.overlay  ainput=rivers atype=line binput=lakes btype=area operator=and output=output
```

however, `v.overlay` returns the `ERROR: Attribute not found`.

What would be the probable cause of this error?